# Why does this compile? [C++]

Tags: c++, compilation

I tried to look for an answer online but couldn't quite find it.

Today I saw these lines of code:

```
    int main(){
    int n = 7;
    while(n /= 10);
    }
```

It doesn't make much sense, but the question was only 'will it compile?'.
To which I answered no, but I was wrong.

My question is, why? Why does

```
    n /= 10
```

behave like a bool (or an int) here?

Comment: Any non-zero value is treated as `true` in C++.

Comment: The operator /= is correct and is equivalent to : ( n = n / 10)
Just like the += operator which is equivalent to : (n = n / 10)

Comment: You're going to be horrified in the future by how much compiles when you don't want it to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An assignment (including a compound assignment like `/=`) is an expression, which yields the value that was assigned<sup>1</sup>.

So, you can do something like: `x = y = z = 0;`, which assigns 0 to `z`, takes the result of that (also 0) and assigns it to `y`, and takes the result of that (still 0) and assigns it to `x`.

From there, it's making use of the implicit conversion from `int` to `bool`, in which `0` converts to `false`, and any non-zero value converts to `true`.

---

<sup>1. Note: that's what happens for built-in types. By convention, when/if you overload `operator=` for a class, you have it `return *this;`, so it works the same way, as a user would/will expect--but that part's not mandatory--you *can* overload your `operator=` to return a different value or an entirely different type--but this is almost always a bad idea and should usually be avoided.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

What you have here for your while loop is as follows:

```
while ( expression );
```

If the expression is `true` or `non 0` the loop will continue; otherwise if it evaluates to `false` or `0` it will terminate. So looking back at your original:

```
int n = 7;
while ( n /= 10 );
```

This then becomes:

```
while ( n = 7 / 10 );
```

Here the full expression is `n = 7 / 10`; This should result in `0` due to truncation of integer arithmetic. The value by implicit conversion from `int` to `bool` becomes `false`. As the yielded result is `0`.

There is nothing here preventing this from compiling. As this is no different than having:

```
while ( false );
```

However with assignment and arithmetic operations; this may not always be the case, but in your case it is. Consider this next example: This will still compile but the loop will not terminate:

```
int n = 5;
while( n + n );
```

This will then become:

```
while( 5 + 5 );
...
while( 10 );
...
while( true );
```

Which will still compile but the loop will continue infinitely.

Comment: Isn't `n = 7/10` going to be 0, since the values are integers? Aside from that the answer is pretty clear.

Comment: @auouo 7/10 depends on the compiler and how it does integer arithmetic. If it truncates it then yes it would be `0` and `false` but if it doesn't and see's that it's a non `0` value it will treat it as `true`. However I think you are correct about it being `0`.

Comment: @auouo I've edited my answer to reflect that as I forgot about the truncation....

Answer (score 0):

Just like `+=` and `-=` work, `*=` and `/=` work.

In fact, there are also `&=` and `|=`.

These all evaluate to the new value that has been assigned.

And, as you know, you don't have to put a boolean in a `while`/`for`/`if` condition; you only need to put something there that can be *converted* to a boolean.

For example, `if (42)`, or `for (char* ptr = begin; ptr; ++ptr)`, or `while (n /= 10)`.

Answer (score -1):

C++ will convert the n /= 10 to bool. Integers = 0 converted to bool evaluates to false. Integers != 0 converted to bool evaluates to true. 
That while will be evaluated as `while(false)`.

Comment: No, it won't run forever because `n` will change each loop iteration.

Comment: Integers != 0 are false.

Comment: @stark: No, integers == 0 are false, integers != 0 are true.

Comment: in fact it wont run even once

Comment: Editet, Integers !=0 are true.

Comment: So... why won't it run?

Comment: @JacoAlberts 7 / 10 is 0 i.e. false.

Comment: @JacoAlberts "_So... why won't it run?_" operator `/=`, for built-in types, return the value that was assigned. Since `n` is `7` before the first iteration, the `n /= 10` will return `0`, which would be treated as `false`, and hence, not a single iteration of the loop body would be evaluated.

Comment: It does run, not forever though. n is an int, 7 / 10 = 0.7, convert to int = 0, result is false. So it runs once. There is no loop body to execute in this example. Bit I agree, if there was a loop body, it would not be executed. Just saying, the program runs.

Comment: Updated original answer

Comment: @JacoAlberts "_Bit I agree, if there was a loop body, it would not be executed._" There is a loop body. It consists of a single, empty, statement.